# Theming of a webform node

Tags: theming, webforms

i would to theme a specific webform page and i achieve this with devel themer help but i find it not logical.
Usually i use ID to specify a template for a page, node or other element.
Then in my case i use the node-419.tpl for my node 419.normal
For my page it's a bit more complicated because this the hierarchical applied template :

```
page-infos-profil-élève.tpl.php < page-webform.tpl.php < page-node-419.tpl.php < page-node.tpl.php < page.tpl.php
```

so why a template called page-webform-419.tpl.php doesn't work instead of page-infos-profil-élève.tpl.php ?
Could i do this with php in my template.php file ? if yes how ?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes i figure it out like this:

```
function cyrano_pf_preprocess(&$vars, $hook)
{
    switch($hook)
  {
      case 'page' :
      if (arg(0) == 'node')
      {
        $vars['template_files'][]  = 'page-' . $vars['node']->type;
        $vars['template_files'][] = "page-" . $vars['node']->type . "-" . $vars['node']->nid;

      }
      break;

  }

}
```

with the help of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8956045/how-can-i-customize-a-specific-node-in-drupal-6-when-a-custom-template-has-alrea , then i get this choice for now (from devel) :

```
Candidate template files:
page-pentreprise.tpl.php < page-webform-420.tpl.php < page-webform.tpl.php < page-node-420.tpl.php < page-node.tpl.php < page.tpl.php
```

now, i can use a tpl file like page-webform-999.tpl to theme a specific webform page..

Answer (score 2):

This depends on your template suggestions.

Open `template.php` in your theme folder, and look for a function named `YOURTHEME_preprocess_page`, if it does not exist, create it like:

```
function YOURTHEMENAME_preprocess_page(&$vars)
{
    debug($vars['theme_hook_suggestions']);
}
```

And see what suggestions (and in what order) you have.

**EDIT**: this is a preprocess function I used in a theme of mine, in theme's template.php:

```
/**
 * Implementation of hook_preprocess_page()
 * @param $vars
 */
function THEMENAME_preprocess_page(&$vars){
    // I like to store templates in different folders inside the theme dir
    foreach($vars['theme_hook_suggestions'] AS $i => $ths){
        $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][$i] = 'pages/' . $ths;
    }
}
/**/
```

In your case, simply do `debug($vars, 'preprocess page vars!');` to see what variables you have a dispostion (please note: flush the cache after editing/creating this kind of function, and the output of debug($vars) can be very big!) and then add your template suggestion.

Maybe this can help: [theming d7 webforms](http://codekarate.com/daily-dose-of-drupal/theming-drupal-7-webform)

Comment: My suggestions are provided by devel themer module..do your function give me more infos ?

Comment: Ah ok, devel module is probably more accurate.. have you tryed to clear (flush) the cache?

A lot of problems like this one can be solved just clearing the cache.

Comment: yes i clear cache all the time i modify a tpl or css...but if devel doesn't suggest page-webform-419.tpl.php i think it's an issue in my template.php, because i have a code to get template suggestion like page-[content-type] into...?

Comment: Wait, devel *does* or *does not* suggest `page-webform-419.tpl.php` ?
If not, follow my advice; In the preprocess page you can *add* suggestions, just identify when is the page that you need and then add the suggestion ;)

Comment: exact, but i get an error with : `function Cyrano_PF_preprocess(&$vars, $hook)
{
  switch($hook)
  {
      case 'page' :
      if (arg(0) == 'node')
      {
        $vars['template_files'][]  = 'page-' . $vars['node']->type;
      }
      break;

  }
    debug($vars['theme_hook_suggestions']);
}`

Comment: What error do you get?
However remove uppercase from function name..

Comment: Take a look here: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_page/7

Comment: i get error 500 but i figure it out for now with `function Cyrano_PF_preprocess(&$vars, $hook)
{
     
  switch($hook)
  {
      case 'page' :
      if (arg(0) == 'node')
      {
        $vars['template_files'][]  = 'page-' . $vars['node']->type;
      }
      break;
debug($vars['theme_hook_suggestions']);
  }
   
}` but nothing is displayed on screen , is it normal ?

Comment: Let me update my answer with few details..

Comment: ok i saw your edit but nothing is display with : `function cyrano_pf_preprocess(&$vars, $hook)
{
   switch($hook)
  {
      case 'page' :
      if (arg(0) == 'node')
      {
        $vars['template_files'][]  = 'page-' . $vars['node']->type;
        
      }
      break;
debug($vars, 'preprocess page vars!');
  }
   
}` if i put your code into the case, i get an 500 error.But why this code would provide suggestions that devel don't ?

Comment: That code (hook_prepocess_page function) is used to **add or remove** suggestions; Devel module only **show** the suggestions for a element..

Comment: remove your switch, and in the function just put `debug($hook, 'HOOK'); debug($vars, 'VARS');` and see the output. If you get the 500 error in this way, is probably becose $vars is too big to be debugged, try then `debug(array_keys($vars), 'Vars keys');` and then again debug just the keys you need.

Comment: 500 error in both cases..empty cache or run cron do no change. :(  `function cyrano_pf_preprocess(&$vars, $hook)
{
     debug(array_keys($vars), 'Vars keys');
//   debug($hook, 'HOOK'); debug($vars, 'VARS');
   
}`

Comment: Well, check the error log of your server (apache i guess, should be in /var/log/apache2/ named error.log or yourdomain.error.log, depends on your apache configuration) to see what is the problem

Comment: `[Thu Sep 26 14:11:13 2013] [error] [client 192.168.100.23] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function debug() in /var/www/drupal6/sites/all/themes/Cyrano_PF/template.php on line 16, r$
[Thu Sep 26 14:12:21 2013] [error] [client 192.168.100.23] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function debug() in /var/www/drupal6/sites/all/themes/Cyrano_PF/template.php on line 5, re$
`